# Obtaining final classifier in RTextTools

Tags: r, classification, text-mining

I have a question concerning the RTextTools package. When I was reading textbooks and wikipedia I imagined that text classification is all about defining a classificator. In RTextTools you define learning and testing documents in one command. For example

```
data <- data[sample(1:3100,size=100,replace=FALSE),]
matrix <- create_matrix(cbind(data$Title,data$Subject), language="english",
removeNumbers=TRUE, stemWords=FALSE, weighting=weightTfIdf)
corpus <- create_corpus(matrix,data$Topic.Code,trainSize=1:75, testSize=76:100,virgin=FALSE)
models <- train_models(corpus, algorithms=c("MAXENT","SVM"))
```

We create a corpus from one dataset, where like first 75 documents is for learning and the rest is for training.
But when it comes to applying text classification theories for practical use, you want already predefined text classificator to be applied for different datasets. For now the only solution i managed to find is to train with the same documents and then use different test data. But it sounds very unconfortable when it comes to large texts. So my question is how to create predefined classificator and then apply it to different datasets with R? It would be preferable to use algorithms from RTextTools.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to documentation, you need function `classify_models` (excerpt from the documentation page):

> **Description**
>
> Uses a trained model from the train_models function to classify new
>   data.
>
> **Usage**
>
> `classify_models(corpus, models, ...)`
>
> **Arguments**
>
> `corpus`   Class of type matrix_container-class generated by the
>   `create_corpus` function.
>
> `models`   List of models to be used for classification generated by
>   `train_models`.
>
> `...`  Other parameters to be passed on to classify_model.

Here is the reproducible example:

```
###Train model (taken out of `classify_model` man page)

library(RTextTools)    
set.seed(123)
alldata <- read_data(system.file("data/NYTimes.csv.gz",package="RTextTools"),type="csv")
smpl <- sample(1:3100,size=100)
data <- alldata[smpl,]
matrix <- create_matrix(cbind(data$Title,data$Subject), language="english", 
removeNumbers=TRUE, stemWords=FALSE, weighting=weightTfIdf)
corpus <- create_corpus(matrix,data$Topic.Code,trainSize=1:75, testSize=76:100, 
virgin=FALSE)

models <- train_models(corpus, algorithms=c("MAXENT","SVM"))

###Create new data which you want to classify: 

newdata <- alldata[sample((1:3100)[-smpl],size=101,replace=FALSE),]

newmatrix <- create_matrix(cbind(newdata$Title,newdata$Subject), language="english", 
removeNumbers=TRUE, stemWords=FALSE, weighting=weightTfIdf)

newcorpus <- create_corpus(newmatrix,newdata$Topic.Code,trainSize=1:1, testSize=2:101, 
virgin=FALSE)


newresults1 <- classify_model(newcorpus,models[[1]])
newresults2 <- classify_model(newcorpus,models[[2]])
```

The last line should produce the error, since the new data has some terms which were not present in the data used to produce the models. To circumvent this, it is better to use `create_matrix` on all the data you have, and then to train model on the sample of result of `create_matrix`, instead of the original data.

This solution is a bit quirky, since the convenience function `classify_models` demands a `corpus`, where train and test data sets must be explicitly defined. Since the goal is to use the classifier, all data is test data. In this solution I sidestepped the problem by selecting only one observation for train  and all the others for the test. To sidestep this it is possible to use `predict` method directly:

```
predict(models[[1]],as.compressed.matrix(newmatrix))
```

Comment: > predict(SVM,as.compressed.matrix(doc_matrix2))
Error in predict.svm(SVM, as.compressed.matrix(doc_matrix2)) : 
  test data does not match model !

Comment: Feels like RTextTools is more of a toy.  It is nearly impossible in a production environment to create the matrix of all the data you have unless perhaps you are TimeLord.

Comment: just to add, if you have the error "test data does not match model", when calling create_matrix for your unclassified set you should be providing argument originalMatrix=(you original training matrix)